# Swapping $k$ vectors of basis with $k$ linearly independent given vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, change-of-basis

It is easy to see that if $B$ is a basis for an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector space, then for every non zero vector $v$ not in $B$, there exists $u\in B$ such that $(B\setminus \{u\})\cup \{v\}$ is still a basis for $V$.

Is the following generalization also true? :

If $B$ is a basis for an arbitrary $n$-dimensional vector space, then every bunch of $k$ linearly independent vectors given, one can swap them with $k$ vectors in $B$, obtaining a basis again?
($k\leq n$)

It seems to me true, no counter example is known to me. But even $k=2$ does not look easy.
Is it a known statement? Is there any “combinatorial proof” (avoiding high linear algebra stuff)?

Answer (score 0):

After choosing an onrdering of your basis $B={b_1,...,b_n}$ you can procede inductively. i.e. consider your set $I_0=I={v_1,...,v_k}$, then you define $I_{i+1}$ by checking if $b_{i+1}\in \langle I_i \rangle$ if so, define $I_{i+1}:=I_i$, otherwise $I_{i+1}=I_{i}\cup\{b_{i+1}\}$. Now you know by construction that all those $I_i$ are linearly independent and that $B\subset \langle I_{n}\rangle$ hence $V \subset \langle I_{n}\rangle$. So we constructed a linearly independent generating set, i.e. a basis! just as you wanted by picking $b_i$. However, be aware that this choices are non canonical (in particular since we chose an order on the basis).

Comment: Thank you so much. I somehow knew this proof, but the point exactly is that I’m seeking for a canonical way to swap the vectors! In particular, suppose we have two basis for an $n$ dimensional vector space and given any $k$ vectors of the first basis, we need to find $k$ vectors from the second basis and swap them such that the resulting two sets remain basis for our vector space. What then? I don’t see how your above method can be mimicked here.

Comment: well the same argument still works in the case you just sketched, $k$ elements of a basis is still only a linear independent set of $k$ vectors. And by the way, if you have ordered basis, this is more or less canonical!

Comment: Ok. Maybe I could not get my point across. Let me put it this way: Suppose $B$ and $B’$ are two basis for an $n$ dimensional vector space $V$. Is it true that for every $K\subset B$, there exists $K’\subset B’$ such that $|K|=|K’|$ and both $(B\setminus K)\cup K’$ and $(B’\setminus K’)\cup K$ are still basis for $V$? Can the method above be adapted here?